# Alternative to Underscore.me for gen custom blank theme

Tags: themes, web-services

I see that the website underscore.me is no longer available for generating Wordpress theme templates. Is there an alternative to underscore.me for Wordpress theme generation?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have the wrong URL. You want: https://underscores.me

Comment: oops! I don't know how that happened. I'm pretty sure I followed a link directly from within Wordpress where underscores.me was identified as... incorrect somehow. then I went down a rabbit hole. 

Thanks for your reply!